# How to use a sequence of statements in Boost.Phoenix together with std::transform?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-phoenix

I'd like to use Boost.Phoenix to create a lambda function that consists of a few lines of code and then "returns" a value so I can use it together with `std::transform`.

Like this:

```
std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(),
        (
            //Do something complicated here with the elements of a:
            statement1,
            statement2,
            statement3
            //Is there a way to return a value here?
        )
        );
```

With `std::for_each` this would work perfectly, but with `std::transform` it does not compile because the comma operator returns `void`. How can I return a value from a lambda function like this?

---

Edit: I changed the code fragment because what I wrote in the first place led to misunderstandings about what I want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this isn't possible. From the [Boost.Phoenix v2 statement docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/spirit/phoenix/doc/html/phoenix/composite.html#phoenix.composite.statement.for__statement):

> Unlike lazy functions and lazy operators, lazy statements always return void.

(Note that this same assertion is in the Boost.Phoenix v3 docs as well.)

Answer (score 1):

In functional programming, it's not the intention to change state.  However, instead of using `for_each`, you may use `accumulate`.  Accumulating implies you have a 'starting value' (e.g. m=1,n=0), and a function that 'adds' a value to an output value:

```
#include <vector>

struct MN { int m, n; 
  MN(int m,int n):m(m),n(n){}
  static MN accumulate( MN accumulator, int value ) {
     return MN( accumulator.m + value, accumulator.n * value );
  }
}; // your 'state'

int main(){
  std::vector<int> v(10,10); // { 10, 10, ... }
  MN result = std::accumulate( v.begin(), v.end(), MN(0,1), MN::accumulate );
  printf("%d %d", result.m, result.n );
}
```

I'm unfamilar with Phoenix, but probably there is a way to define the `MN::accumulate` function in terms of it.

Comment: Maybe I should have made clearer that the code fragment I posted in the first place was just supposed to be an example and has not much to do with my actual problem. My problem involves complicated data structures and `std::transform` is definitively the only standard algorithm I can use. I updated the question to clarify this.